# iOS: without auto layout and size class UI work for Universal devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-autolayout, size-classes, ios-universal-app

I have two project. 
In First project does't use any size class or any auto layout still it's UI is same in all devices. It's a universal App. (I get the source of this project from out side) 
And second project I create my own and try to replicate that first project but still my UI is not universal. 
Here is the snap of that two project. 
[image]

Please help me to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your project?

Comment: Your snaps shows file preferences for storyboard, not a size inspecter - if there is anything like that in Xcode. Most likely, the project you got from outside does all the layouting in code, but it's hard to say without actually looking at it.

Comment: Ya! I look into the code but still no coding related to constrains.

Comment: If you need to any snap for observe the project than tell me. I put that snap.